# System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column Reserve By Staff on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to run the form but it turns into break mode.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column
>   Reserve By Staff on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember'

```vb
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.Data

    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub ReservationBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReservationBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.ReservationBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me._123DataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_123DataSet.Reservation' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.ReservationTableAdapter.Fill(Me._123DataSet.Reservation)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim CONNECTION As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        CONNECTION.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Asus\Documents\123.mdb"

        If ReservationIDTextBox.Text = Nothing Or VenueIDComboBox.Text = Nothing Or ReserveDateDateTimePicker.Text = Nothing Or ReserveStartTimeDateTimePicker.Text = Nothing Or ReserveEndTimeDateTimePicker.Text = Nothing Or NOAComboBox.Text = Nothing Or ReserveByStaffTextBox.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Please Fill in All Field", vbInformation, "note")
        Else
            'On Error GoTo SaveErr
            'ReservationBindingSource.EndEdit()
            'ReservationTableAdapter.Update(Event_Venue_Reservation_SystemDataSet.Reservation)
            'MessageBox.Show("Reserved!")
            'SaveErr:
            'Exit Sub
            'End If
            Try

                CONNECTION.Open()
                Dim query As String
                query = "INSERT INTO [Reservation] ([ReservationID],[VenueID], [ReserveDate], [ReserveStartTime], [ReserveEndTime], [NumberofAttendees], [ReserveByStaff])" + "VALUES ('" & ReservationIDTextBox.Text & "','" & VenueIDComboBox.Text & "','" & ReserveDateDateTimePicker.Text & "','" & ReserveStartTimeDateTimePicker.Text & "','" & ReserveEndTimeDateTimePicker.Text & "','" & NOAComboBox.Text & "','" & ReserveByStaffTextBox.Text & "')"

                Dim Cmd1 = New OleDbCommand(query, CONNECTION)
                Dim Reader = Cmd1.ExecuteReader

                MessageBox.Show("Reserved!")
                CONNECTION.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Finally
                CONNECTION.Dispose()
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
        StaffFunction.Show()
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        ReservationBindingSource.AddNew()
        Call autoid()
    End Sub
    Sub autoid()
        Dim CONNECTION As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        CONNECTION.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Asus\Documents\123.mdb"
        CONNECTION.Open()
        Try
            Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand("select Max([ReservationID]) from Reservation", CONNECTION)
            Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If dr.Read = True Then
                Me.ReservationIDTextBox.Text = dr.Item(0) + 1
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        CONNECTION.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
        ReservationBindingSource.MovePrevious()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        ReservationBindingSource.MoveNext()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
        ReservationBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
        On Error GoTo SaveErr
        ReservationBindingSource.EndEdit()
        ReservationTableAdapter.Update(_123DataSet.Reservation)
        MessageBox.Show("Reservation Cancelled!")
SaveErr:
        Exit Sub
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please limit the code to the area that is causing the error? I would suggest modifying your `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` to add a string indicating which block of code is giving the error.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I actually dk which part is wrong... thats why i'm copy all the code here.. this is my assignment and my lecturer dk how to solve this problem also

Comment: 'Cannot bind to the property or column Reserve By Staff on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember'  I ady check the spelling of ReserveByStaff in my access database its correct

Comment: Please try my suggestion: modify all your `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` lines to add where you are in the code. For example: `MessageBox.Show("Error Opening Connection" & vbNewLine & ex.Message)`

Comment: still cannot... get the same error 'Cannot bind to the property or column Reserve By Staff on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember'

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Access has a build in auto increment field that can be used as a primary key. Please do not roll your own. It can make a mess if this app ever becomes multi user and is completely unnecessary.

Comment: `On Error GoTo` No! You are familiar with `Try...End Try`. Use it. Also you might want to temporarily comment out all error trapping until you fix your problem. Then you will know what line is causing the problem.

Comment: I thought there are problem with the data source?